# How to get first image in tt_content for meta og:image

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to fetch the first existing image in tt_content to be used in Open Graph (og:image) if any images in tt_content.

```
page.headerData {
    1 = COA
    1 {
        10 = FILES
        10 {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                uid.field = uid
                fieldName = image
            }
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                typolink {
                    parameter.data = file:current:publicUrl
                    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                    returnLast = url
                }
                wrap = |,
            }
            stdWrap {
                listNum = 0
                # Use logo image if none is available
                ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
                ifEmpty.cObject.typolink {
                    parameter = typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Public/Images/logo.png
                    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                    returnLast = url
                }
                wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|">
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above only returns the fallback (logo). Great for pages and tt_content without images, but I would expect different from pages with image(s) in tt_content.

Answer (score 3):

I report here the nice snippet found on https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/docs-snippets/master/en-us/2014/Index.html#add-facebook-open-graph-og-image-metatags-for-content-elements-with-typo3-6-0-and-fal

I simplified it a bit; hope it is not too much simplified but it should work:

```
page.headerData.200 = CONTENT
page.headerData.200 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    where = {#colPos}=0
    selectFields = uid
  }
  renderObj = FILES
  renderObj {
    references {
      table = tt_content
      uid.field = uid
      fieldName = image
    }
    maxItems = 1
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      data = file:current:publicUrl
      stdWrap {
        wrap = <meta name="og:image" content="|" >
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Perfect @riccardo-de-contardi ! I've made a tiny improvement postet below

Comment: @prathers I think you don't need at all the typolink :)

Comment: Second you should be able to simplify the path: EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/Images/logo.png

Comment: Thanks @riccardo - simplifying TS is added to my goals of improvements! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is @riccardo-de-contardi's snippet with a fallback

```
page.headerData.1569221029 = CONTENT
page.headerData.1569221029 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        where = {#colPos}=0
        selectFields = uid
    }
    renderObj = FILES
    renderObj {
        references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.field = uid
            fieldName = image
        }
        maxItems = 1
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
            data = file:current:publicUrl
            stdWrap {
                wrap = |,
            }
        }
    }
    stdWrap {
        listNum = 0
        # Use logo image if none is available
        ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
        ifEmpty.cObject.typolink {
            parameter = typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Public/Images/logo.png
            forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
            returnLast = url
        }
        wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|">
    }
}
```